# powerbuilder .saveas method works for black and white pdf?

Tags: powerbuilder

Whenever I do .saveas for colorful datawindow.. It is giving me black and white pdf file. Is there any solution to get directly colorful print as I want to save it in folder.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention what version of PB you are using, but I am assumming you are using Ghostscript.  You need to go into your Printers and go to the properties of the "Sybase DataWindow PS" entry.  You need to change Driver to a printer that has "color" and "PS" in its name.  That will allow you to save your PDFs in color.

[image: Example]